# Phaser 2 determining which unit is active

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have 3 clickable objects. When one is clicked, this becomes the 'selected unit'.
I am trying to create some generic actions for the units such as moving to a point.

In my create function I initialize the units, when a unit is clicked on - this is supposed to become the 'selected unit' so that my movement and direction function applies to the this unit.  However, the script is not able to recognize which unit intend for example I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'velocity' of undefined.

Is there a way to use a variable to indicate selected users and pass that to the functions?

```
window.onload = function() {
    
    var block_count   = 0;
    var block         = '';
    var selected_unit = '';
    var unit_clicked = 0;
    var tank1 = null;
    
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render});

    function preload () {
        game.load.image('block', 'block.png');
        game.load.image('tank1', 'tank.png');
        game.load.image('baddie', 'tank.png');
        game.load.image('mouse_btn', 'block.png');
        game.input.mouse.capture = true;
    }
            
    function create () {
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        
        mouse_btn = game.add.sprite(30,30, 'mouse_btn');
        mouse_btn.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        
        
        //T1
        tank1 = game.add.sprite(30,30, 'tank1');
        initialise_player(tank1);
        game.physics.enable(tank1, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        
        //T2
        tank2 = game.add.sprite(30,60, 'tank1');
        initialise_player(tank2);
        game.physics.enable(tank2, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        
        game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
        game.camera.follow(tank1);
    }


            
    function update () {
    
        if(selected_unit == '') {
            mouse_btn.x = game.input.mousePointer.worldX
            mouse_btn.y = game.input.mousePointer.worldY
        }           
        
        if(game.input.activePointer.leftButton.isDown && block_count == 0 && unit_clicked == 0) {
            game.input.activePointer.leftButton.stop(event);
            block_count =1;
            block = game.add.sprite(game.input.mousePointer.worldX, game.input.mousePointer.worldY, 'block');
            game.physics.enable(block, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            block.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5)
            lookAtObject(selected_unit, block, 0.005);
        }
        
        
        if(block.alive){
            game.physics.arcade.moveToObject(selected_unit, block, 260, 0)
        } else {
            console.log(selected_unit)
            selected_unit.body.velocity.x = 0;
            selected_unit.body.velocity.y = 0;
        }
        
        if(game.physics.arcade.collide(selected_unit, block)) {
            block_count--;
            block.kill();
        }
    }

    function render(){
        //console.log(game.physics.arcade.collide(tank1, block))
    }
    
    function lookAtObject(obj, target, rotspeed){
        var angle = Math.atan2(block.y - tank1.y, block.x - tank1.body.x);
        tank1.rotation = angle + game.math.degToRad(90);
    }

    function initialise_player(tank1){
      tank1.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
      tank1.inputEnabled = true;
      tank1.input.useHandCursor = true;
      tank1.events.onInputDown.add(t1_clicked,this);
      tank1.events.onInputOver.add(t1_over, this)
      tank1.events.onInputOut.add(t1_out, this)
   }
    
  function t1_clicked() { 
    selected_unit = tank1;
}

function t1_over() { 
    unit_clicked = 1
}

function t1_out () { 
    unit_clicked = 0
}
    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting on initial load is because in `update` you're making an assumption that `selected_unit` exists and has a `body`.

Update your third `if` to make sure `selected_unit` is defined.

```
if (selected_unit !== '') {
    selected_unit.body.velocity.x = 0;
    selected_unit.body.velocity.y = 0;
}
```

However, a better option would be to put this a few lines down, where you kill the block instead.

```
if(game.physics.arcade.collide(selected_unit, block)) {
    selected_unit.body.velocity.x = 0;
    selected_unit.body.velocity.y = 0;
    block_count--;
    block.kill();
}
```

`if (block.alive)`; `moveToObject` is also expecting `selected_unit` to exist and have a `body`, which may not be the case; wrap it with a check.

```
if (selected_unit !== '') {
    game.physics.arcade.moveToObject(selected_unit, block, 260, 0)
}
```

That now allows `tank1` to rotate to look at the item you just placed, but it doesn't move it until it or `tank2` have been clicked on.

This also points out that there are a number of tweaks you'll want to make to your code in general, since you're ignoring arguments that are being passed in. For example, `t1_clicked` isn't using the sprite that's been clicked on, but is instead just hard-coding `tank1`. `lookAtObject` isn't using `obj` or `target`, but again has values hard-coded in.

One other thing you may want to change is the following:

```
if(selected_unit == '') {
    mouse_btn.x = game.input.mousePointer.worldX
    mouse_btn.y = game.input.mousePointer.worldY
}
```

If you make that the following, you won't end up with an extra sprite hanging about on the screen.

```
if (block_count === 0) {
    mouse_btn.x = game.input.mousePointer.worldX;
    mouse_btn.y = game.input.mousePointer.worldY;
}
```